# Email a picture from photo library

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I want to compose an email with picture taken from camera or photo library. But i am unable to open Mail composer picker.

Here is my code:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    UIImage* image_type=[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    dataImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image_type);

    if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailCont = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailCont.delegate=self;
        mailCont.mailComposeDelegate = self;        // Required to invoke mailComposeController when send
        [mailCont setSubject:@""];
        [mailCont setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@""]];
        [mailCont addAttachmentData:dataImage mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"sender_image.png"];
        [mailCont setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:NO];

        [self presentModalViewController:mailCont animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Now the mail picker is not opening. The warning is :

```
Warning: Attempt to present <MFMailComposeViewController: 0xa26b070> on <UINavigationController: 0xa22e6d0> while a presentation is in progress!
```

How can i handle this.

Comment: You can shift the mail composing code to a separate function and call that function with some delay using the performSelector: withObject: afterDelay:

Comment: @Adi This is not an optimal solution since there is no garantie that self has been dismissed after some arbitrary time ε. It should be done after the view dismissal finished.

Comment: Thanks @PraveenS to tell me new thigns.. It works great...

Comment: @Filip Sure.. Agree with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are first dismissing the UIImagePicker and then immediately trying to display another view as modal view. This has to be done after the dismissal finished. Try this instead:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                             completion:^{
                                 UIImage* image_type=[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
                                 dataImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image_type);

                                 if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
                                 {
                                     MFMailComposeViewController *mailCont = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
                                     mailCont.delegate=self;
                                     mailCont.mailComposeDelegate = self;        // Required to invoke mailComposeController when send
                                     [mailCont setSubject:@""];
                                     [mailCont setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@""]];
                                     [mailCont addAttachmentData:dataImage mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"sender_image.png"];
                                     [mailCont setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:NO];

                                     [self presentModalViewController:mailCont animated:YES];
                                 }
                             }];
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: @shivam Sweet! Perhaps an +1 and an accepted answer would be in order! ;)